# dojo/cbtree uncheck all checkboxes and check selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo

I want to make the **checkbox** work more or less like a **radio button** in this instance. This is what I have so far. I would like to be able to do this in the `treeCheckboxClicked()` function so that it would just uncheck all the remaining checkboxs then check the one that was selected.

```
buildTocTree: function (cp1) {
    var self = this;
            var toc = new TOC({
                checkboxes: false,
                enableDelete: true,
                deleteRecursive: true,
                showRoot: false,
                checkBoxes: false,
            }, self._viewId + '_tocTree');
    toc.on("checkBoxClick", dojo.hitch(this, "treeCheckboxClicked"));
},

treeCheckboxClicked: function (e) {  
            if (e.checked) {
                if (e.subLayers || e.name === 'GISLayer')
                    this.selectedLayerValue('');
                else if (e.layerInfos)
                    this.selectedLayerValue('');
                else
                    this.selectedLayerValue(e.name);

                if (this.selectedLayerValue() != '')
                    this._selectedGISSourceLayer = e;
                else
                    this._selectedGISSourceLayer = '';
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the internal details of the TOC widget, especially its DOM, it's difficult to know how to query all checkboxes within its template. Assuming your `treeCheckboxClicked` is already getting called, and `e.target` is the checkbox element itself, the following code should get you close to your desired functionality:

```
if (e.checked) {
    query('checkbox', self.domNode).forEach(function (checkbox) {
        checkbox.checked = checkbox != e.target;
    });

    //...
}
```

*Note: This assumes the dojo/query module has been loaded.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you using agsjs.TOC?  They have a handler included to do this for you.  In the examplesat http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/tags/agsjs/latest/examples/toc.html they toggle the function off and on with a button, but you can make it default on and include the following snippet in your tree declaration. (replace DynaLayer 1 with your layer)

```js
toc.on('toc-node-checked', function(evt){
 // when check on one layer, turn off everything else on the public safety service.
 if (evt.checked && evt.rootLayer && evt.serviceLayer && evt.rootLayer == dynaLayer1){
 evt.rootLayer.setVisibleLayers([evt.serviceLayer.id])
    }
```